# JPA get parent from child

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, servlets

I have two tables Companies and Users, where each company has many users, and I want to do a query on the users table where the column `IS_VERIFED` equals false. In my User entitie I set the `XMLTransient` property on the `getCompany` method to avoid an infinite loop of the user getting the company and the company getting the user.

I preform my query to get all the users that are not verifed, which return a `List<User>`. But I also want to return the company that each User belong to.

I can loop through the `users` array like this

```
List<User> users = entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.getPendingUsers").getResultList();
        for (User user : users) {
            logger.debug(user.getCompany().getCompanyId() + "");
            logger.debug(user.getCompany().getCompanyName() + "");
        }
```

And I see the company ID and name printed out, but now I want to return that list of users with the companies referenced how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You want `List<User> users = runQuery("select * from user where company_id=123")` list? You wish to have `user.getCompany().getUsers()` jpa getter?

Comment: Nobody can tell you what query to use or what to call UNLESS you post the ENTITY classes!